# make button toggle method — objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 4 buttons. When they are taped they each create a UIView underneath it, they expand under the buttons. I want the view to go back to its original when the buttons are taped a second time. How is this done?

Comment: You mean you want to remove the view or what?

Comment: I think he want to expand a view the first time and collapse the second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set every tag button to 0, change it to the opposite value when you press the button. Here is what you'll get:

1. First time that you press the button: button's tag = 0, expand the view and turn it to 1.
2. Second time you press the button: button's tag = 1, collapse it and turn it to 0.

So you haven't to create a bool for every button but you can use your button's tag variable.
Code should be like this.

```
- (void)handleButton:(UIButton *)button{
    if(button.tag == 0) { <expandButton> }
    else                { <collapseButton> }

    button.tag = !button.tag;
}
```

Comment: but how do I check if its the second time the button has been touched?

Comment: I've written the code to use: the first time button.tag will be 0. If you change it to 1, the second time the button you pressed the first time will have a tag value of 1.

Comment: that will work unless you use the tag as your way to identity each of the 4 buttons

Comment: Good point, in that case I think he has two choice: use a bool value for every button (or better an array of bool values to make it looks better) or create a var for every button, linking it with the xib, to identify the pressed button with its instance. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: can you post your code? It seems strange, I use the same for my project purpose

Answer (score 1):

Set an instance BOOL and flip it accordingly.  In the IBAction the button is tied to check the BOOL and call the appropriate method to adjust the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `selected` property of your button, something like:

```
-(void)yourButtonIsTapped:(UIButton*)button {
   if(button.selected) { //first time
       //expand the view
      button.selected = NO;
   }
   else { // second time
      //hide view
      button.selected = YES;
   }
}
```

You can link the buttons from the IB th this method for the `touchUpInside` event but you will have to change the return type from `void` to `IBAction`.

And I think there are several other solutions for this case but this is the faster one and the easiest to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a view simply by calling

```
[viewUnderButton removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: but how do I check if its the second time the button has been touched?